# Send message to user by Full Name

Tags: slack, slack-api

With Slack's webhook, you can send a message to a specific user if you know their display name:

```
{
 "text": "hello world",
 "channel" "@display_name"
}
```

How can one send a message to the user if only their "Full Name" is known.

i.e. In scenarios where you want to warn a specific user but you only know their Full Name as held in a third-party service (GSuite, AWS etc).

Comment: Well you need to correlate the external name to the user ID in slack. That may mean generating a map of Names to User IDs. There's no guarantee that a user's "full name" has anything to do with their slack account

Comment: @jsarbour we do mandate conforming slack full names to HR records, so it would be handy to be able to reference people by full name on slack

Comment: sounds like we ll have to do this through the api

Answer (score 0):

Since users can freely change their full name on Slack at any time I would advise against relying on mapping by full name.

However you can do it by retrieving the user list from the API with [`users.list`](https://api.slack.com/methods/users.list) and then trying to match a given full name to the list of names.

A better way would be to create and store the mapping between the Slack user ID and your employee ID when the account is created.

Just to give you the full picture: If you have the user ID you can still send a direct message to them by using their user ID as channel ID.